Seeking Guidance on Controlling Coarsening Ratios in Networkit's nk.coarsening
I've been diving into the world of Networkit lately and have been experimenting with the nk.coarsening module for network coarsening. While I find the functionality quite powerful, I'm struggling a bit with understanding how to control the coarsening ratios effectively.
Does anyone here have experience with manipulating coarsening ratios using Networkit's nk.coarsening module? I've gone through the documentation, but I'm still a bit unclear on the specifics of this aspect.
Could you please share any insights, tips, or perhaps some code snippets illustrating how one can adjust these ratios precisely? Additionally, if there are any nuances or best practices to keep in mind while doing so, I'd greatly appreciate any guidance you can offer.
Thanks a bunch for your help and expertise! Looking forward to learning from your experiences.
